# Flink on Docker Swarm - Do I need to check the IP Address of the Job Manager to Access Web UI?

Tags: docker, apache-flink, docker-swarm

When running Flink JobManager and Flink TaskManager in a Docker Swarm cluster, there is no guarantee that JobManager will run in any particular node.

If I want to access the Web UI on port 8080, do I need to find out which machine is running JobManager and go to http://ip_address:8080?

What if the node that is running JobManager changes?

Doesn't look like a very straightforward way of working. Is there a way to force the containerised Job Manager to run on a specific node?

I am currently creating the services using the Docker Swarm scripts from:
https://github.com/apache/flink/tree/master/flink-contrib/docker-flink

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

To access a service running in a swarm, you can call any node that is participating in the swarm. The swarm node load balancer will then route the request to an available container. This is provided by the [docker swarm routing mesh](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/ingress/).

Comment: Does it include a swarm manager which has been drained? I drained? I drained the swarm manager, but now I can't access the Flink JobManager using the swarm master's IP address. If I use the IP address of the machine where the Flink JobManager moved to (a swarm worker), then it works fine.

Comment: This is starting to sound like a Docker configuration issue. Docker should work the way yamenk is saying, where you can connect to any node in the swarm, and I've run Flink on Docker that way successfully. I would suggest you open up a new question and post your docker-compose file.